# How to connect to Google Play Games room after creation?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using *BaseGameActivity* and the sample *Button Clicker 2000* for developing my multiplayer game and I'm have trouble once creating a room..

The room is created that way:

```
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 3, 0);
RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
```

Then: `getGamesClient().createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());`

Everything seems ok because the method **onRoomCreated()** is called and I can get the romm id etc.

BUT, the **connectedToRoom()** method is never called !

Right after the room creation I just switch to another `Fragment` (my game is based on a single `Activity`and multiple `Fragment`) as a waiting room in which I display participant's name, icon etc

When I press the back button I switch back to the main screen (another `Fragment`) and here's what should happend:

```
if (mRoomId != null) {
getGamesClient().leaveRoom(this, mRoomId);
mRoomId = null;
```

I can't leave a room I'm to connected to (*mRoomId* is null because I don't call **connectedToRoom()** in which I get the room id)

So what I'm missing ? I can't find the answer on the google play services tutorial..

Comment: Just to make sure, you have another account on a different device that is joining your room?  If not, then you only get to OnRoomCreated().

Comment: Oh..Are you telling me that if I'm the only one in the room, I'll never get connected to it ?! I can't test with another accound at the moment but if you're right, I thank you.

Comment: Yes, until the Google Play Servers connect two or more players, then you won't get past OnRoomCreated().   Then, when you do have two or more, the final call that all the Players (creator and joiner(s)) will receive is the OnRoomConnected() call. (which is what I use to start the game play logic)